# Is it possible to pass parameters to NestJS Middleware while cosuming it?

Tags: typescript, express, nestjs, middleware

```
@Injectable()
export default class CookieMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
  constructor(private role: Role) {}

  private isEmpty(user: IUserCookie) {
    return _.some(user, (val) => !!val);
  }

  use(req: ExtendedRequest, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    const token = req.cookies[this.role + 'Authorization'];
    const refreshToken = req.cookies[this.role + 'Refresh'];

    if (!token && !refreshToken) throw new AuthorizationError();

    const refreshData = AuthService.deTokenizData<IUserCookie>(refreshToken);
    let userData = AuthService.deTokenizData<IUserCookie>(token);

    if (!refreshData && !userData) throw new AuthorizationError();

    if (!userData || !refreshData) {
      const tokenType = !userData ? 'Authorization' : 'Refresh';
      const data = !userData
        ? AuthService.deTokenizData<IUserCookie>(refreshToken)
        : userData;

      if (!data) throw new AuthorizationError();

      res.cookie(this.role + tokenType, data);
      userData = data;
    }

    if (this.isEmpty(userData)) throw new AuthorizationError();

    req.user = userData;
    next();
  }
}
```

I have a middleware and i needed to pass some parameters to it. Is it possbile?

I did try mixin CookieMiddleware("some string param") but did not worked

Comment: How are you wanting to pass the parameters to it?

Comment: Why do you need to pass in parameters? What do you want to achieve? (maybe there is another solution - Guards or Pipes)